# if and else both statement executing in java, Android

Tags: java, android

I have made one static function to change fragment

```
/**
 * This will replace fragment with current fragment
 * 
 * @isAddToBackStack if it is true means when you pressback that caller
 *                   fragment will come
 * @bundle If you want to pass any value from one fragment to another
 *         fragment then pass value over here using Bundle
 */

public static int callFragment(Activity mActivity, Fragment mFragment,
        boolean isAddToBackStack, Bundle bundle) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    if (bundle != null) {
        mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.changeFragment, mFragment);
    if (isAddToBackStack) {
        return fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("").commit(); //----------EXECUTING
    } else {
        return fragmentTransaction.commit(); //----------EXECUTING
    }

}
```

I am calling above function by below method

```
Constants.callFragment(MainActivity.this,
                        new MyContactFragment(), true, null);
```

but I have put debug pointer to debug application and I have seen that
some time this if and else both statement are executing

```
if (isAddToBackStack) {
            return fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("").commit(); //----------EXECUTING
        } else {
            return fragmentTransaction.commit(); //----------EXECUTING
        }
```

if anybody know please suggest me what's wrong i am doing

Comment: Not possible. Try debugging again and putting some debug statement around. If you have seen, then it might be two different calls.

Comment: Thanks @SMA but it is right, I will post video on youtube and will show you how debugger is showing yellow line

Comment: How do you know both are executing?

Comment: Use debug.May be this method call two diff cases and execute both case one by one.

Comment: Are you using recursion in your code? This would look like both parts executing at same time. If so, try using step by step debugging and watch the call stack, or add breakpoints before if statement and/or at end of method.